# Monitor or Log messages in Mule ESB

Tags: logging, mule

I want to log or monitor the message payloads processed by Mule ESB. I used the following logger. But it does not log the payload.

```
<logger message="#['Payload is:'+ payload]" level="DEBUG" />
```

Answer (score 5):

Try this one

```
<logger message="Payload is #[message.payloadAs(java.lang.String)]" level="INFO" />
```

Hope this helps.

Comment: This is the best approach, as it will use Mule's auto-transformation capacity to transform the payload into a String, not just call `toString()` on it. Note that if the payload is an input stream, it will be consumed after that so better serialize the stream to `byte[]` or `String`, then log it and keep processing it with the serialized type.

Answer (score 0):

```
<logger level="DEBUG" doc:name="Logger" message="Payload is: #[message.payload]"/>
```

When you see things like: B@19e3bdb what you are seeing is the default String representation of whatever object your message payload is.

It apparently does not implement a toString method that formats the object for you to read as you expect. If you change the logger to just #[message] you will get the whole mule msg, including header info. Among those should be a prop called payload which will tell you the class name/type of your payload.

You then would need to find some documentation or info about that class and decide how to format parts of it in a readable way for your logger. For example if your type has a "name" property that is a String you could do #[message.payload.name] to see the name in your log output.

Comment: Hi, I used your solution too. It is also logged like this. payload is : [B@19e3bdb. It does not log the message. I'm trying to log SOAP messages

Answer (score 0):

```
<logger message="payload is : #[payload]" level="INFO" doc:name="Logger"/>
```

Can also be used

Comment: Hi, I used your solution. Now it is logged like this. payload is : [B@19e3bdb. It does not log the message. I'm trying to log SOAP messages

Comment: Please add you full requirement or the mule config for us to give better answer

Comment: @user3049576 Probably you need a Byte array to string transformer.